# How to make an app save the content of an EditText/TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I want to save some information about users' accounts in an EditText/TextView inside the app. For example I want my app to save in the EditText/TextView the content "Admin" for admin users and "User" for simple users. But I do not want to access the database every time the user opens the app. How can I save the content of the EditText/TextView even if the user decides to exit the app?
The users will not see the EditText/TextView. It will just help me avoid some reads in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save it local / cache the data on the users device.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: Thank you. It might be a silly question, but I am new in Android.